Apache Spark supporting csi driver for volume type
Today Spark supports the following types of Kubernetes volumes: hostPath, emptyDir, nfs and persistentVolumeClaim. In our case we cannot use any of these volumes (see below). In our case csi driver would be useful but it is not currently support by Spark. I filed Jira ticket against Spark requesting this feature.
I wonder how much of community support is out there for this feature to be implemented in Spark.

In our case, Kubernetes cluster is multi-tenant and we cannot make cluster-wide changes when deploying our application to the Kubernetes cluster. Our application requires static shared file system. So, we cannot use hostPath (don't have control of hosting VMs) and persistentVolumeClaim (requires cluster-wide change when deploying PV). Our security department does not allow nfs.
Tried Spark documentation and all supported kubernetes volume types: hostPath, emptyDir, nfs and persistentVolumeClaim.
See Spark supported volume types here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#using-kubernetes-volumes
This is accurate as of Spark 3.5.1
